# PostgreSQL: one index is fast and another one is slow

Tags: postgresql, indexing

We have a database with 450 million rows structured like this:

```
   uid      id_1     id_2   d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6  d7  d8  d9  d10 d11 d12 d13 d14 d15 d16 d17
81038392    5655067 5468882 373 117 185 152 199 173 168 138 185 159 154 34  38  50  34  41  57
81038393    5655067 5468883 374 116 184 118 170 143 144 113 164 137 138 37  39  53  37  42  60
81038394    5655067 5468884 371 118 187 118 170 143 144 105 157 131 136 32  35  47  32  39  53
81038395    5655067 5468885 370 116 184 118 170 143 144 105 157 131 136 31  35  46  31  38  53
81038396    5655067 5468886 370 117 185 118 170 143 144 105 157 131 136 29  34  44  29  37  50
81038397    5655067 5470853 368 117 185 110 163 137 140 105 157 131 136 34  36  48  34  39  55
81038398    5655067 5470854 372 119 188 118 170 143 144 113 164 137 138 34  36  49  34  40  55
81038399    5655067 5470855 360 115 182 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 30  34  45  30  38  51
81038400    5655067 5470856 357 112 177 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 30  34  45  30  37  51
81038401    5655067 5470857 356 111 176 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 28  33  43  28  36  50
81038402    5655067 5470858 358 113 179 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 31  35  46  31  38  52
81038403    5655067 5472811 344 109 173 152 199 173 168 138 185 159 154 31  36  46  31  39  52
81038404    5655068 5468882 373 117 185 152 199 173 168 138 185 159 154 34  38  50  34  41  57
81038405    5655068 5468883 374 116 184 118 170 143 144 113 164 137 138 37  39  53  37  42  60
81038406    5655068 5468884 371 118 187 118 170 143 144 105 157 131 136 32  35  47  32  39  53
81038407    5655068 5468885 370 116 184 118 170 143 144 105 157 131 136 31  35  46  31  38  53
81038408    5655068 5468886 370 117 185 118 170 143 144 105 157 131 136 29  34  44  29  37  50
81038409    5655068 5470853 368 117 185 110 163 137 140 105 157 131 136 34  36  48  34  39  55
81038410    5655068 5470854 372 119 188 118 170 143 144 113 164 137 138 34  36  49  34  40  55
81038411    5655068 5470855 360 115 182 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 30  34  45  30  38  51
81038412    5655068 5470856 357 112 177 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 30  34  45  30  37  51
81038413    5655068 5470857 356 111 176 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 28  33  43  28  36  50
81038414    5655068 5470858 358 113 179 103 151 131 136 98  145 125 131 31  35  46  31  38  52
```

We need to constantly do queries like this:

**Query 1:**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_1 = 5655067;

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using id_1_idx on mytable (cost=0.57..99187.68 rows=25742 width=80) (actual time=47.081..2600.899 rows=21487 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id_1 = 5655067)
   Buffers: shared hit=9 read=4816
   I/O Timings: read=2563.181
 Planning time: 0.151 ms
 Execution time: 2602.320 ms
(6 rows)
```

**Query 2:**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_2 = 5670433;

                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable (cost=442.02..89887.42 rows=23412 width=80) (actual time=113.200..42127.512 rows=21487 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (id_2 = 5670433)
   Heap Blocks: exact=16988
   Buffers: shared hit=30 read=17020
   I/O Timings: read=41971.798
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on id_2_idx  (cost=0.00..436.16 rows=23412 width=0) (actual time=104.928..104.929 rows=21487 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id_2 = 5670433)
         Buffers: shared hit=2 read=60
         I/O Timings: read=99.235
 Planning time: 0.163 ms
 Execution time: 42132.556 ms
(11 rows)
```

There are around 23 000 to 25 000 unique
`id_1` and `id_2` values and both queries will always return around 24 000 rows of the data. We are only reading data and the data does not change over time.

**The problem:**

- The Query 1 takes around 3 seconds, which is a bit much but still bearable.
- The Query 2 takes up to 30-40 seconds, which is way too much for us as the service is interactive web service.

We have indexed `id_1` and `id_2`. We also added a joint index on `id_1` and `id_2` as this was suggested by Azure PostgreSQL As A Service platform where the data is located. It did not help.

My assumption is that the Query 1 is fast since all the rows are located sequentially in the database, whereas when Query 2 is used the the rows are always distributed throughout the whole database non-sequentially.

Restructuring the data to speed up the Query 2 is not a good idea as that would reduce the performance is Query 1. I understand that the way this data is structured is not ideal, but I do not have control over it. Any suggestions how I could speed up the Query 2 to reasonable level?

Edit 2:

Create index statements:

```
CREATE INDEX id_1_idx ON mytable (id_1);
CREATE INDEX id_2_idx ON mytable (id_2);
```

Vacuuming the table did not change the plan. The outputs from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_1 = 5655067` are very similar after the vacuuming. Here is the output from verbose vacuum:

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) mytable;

INFO:  vacuuming "public.mytable"
INFO:  index "mytable_pkey" now contains 461691169 row versions in 1265896 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 2695.21 s.
INFO:  index "id_1_idx" now contains 461691169 row versions in 1265912 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 1493.20 s.
INFO:  index "id_2_idx" now contains 461691169 row versions in 1265912 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 1296.06 s.
INFO:  index "mytable_id_1_id_2_idx" now contains 461691169 row versions in 1265912 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 2364.16 s.
INFO:  "mytable": found 0 removable, 389040319 nonremovable row versions in 5187205 out of 6155883 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 12767
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 13560.60 s.
INFO:  analyzing "public.mytable"
INFO:  "mytable": scanned 30000 of 6155883 pages, containing 2250000 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 461691225 estimated total rows
VACUUM
```

Comment: Does the plan change if you run `vacuum analyze my_table;`? Please also add the `create index`  statements of `id_1_idx` and `id_2_idx`

Comment: It looks like `uid`is a surrogate key and`(id_1,id_2)` is the (natural) candidate key.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the `create index` statements and vacuumed the table. The vacuuming did not change the output from the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_1 = 5655067`, so I did not add the output to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Storage I/O is you major bottleneck + not enough RAM for indexes as you can simply calculate yourself:

For the bitmap heap scan you can calculate an average block read latency of ~2.5 milliseconds (17020 blocks read in 41971.798 ms), which is way too slow.

The only way to avoid disk reads is lots of RAM. Faster storage would make the system far more scalable as most likely this is not the only type of queries and not the only table in the database.

**Long Version**:

Reading the perfect output of the `EXPLAIN` it indicates that the cost evaluation done by the planner is way off and that the performance drop comes from disk reads.

As you wrote that the data does not change over time (and hence, you know the value ranges in advance) you can also range-partition your table on those two columns, which then would have to only scan a certain partition (using smaller indexes, reading smaller table heap). But if the application accessing this data is eventually accessing the full range of data more or less than this would also not help much.

As a result, you should think about replacing the storage subsystem to be able to handle your queries within the performance requirements that your application has.

I have the suspect that the PostgreSQL server is still running on HDD rather than SSD. A little test with only 120M rows shows the following characteristics for both indexes:

```sql
create table nums (uid integer primary key, id_1 integer, id_2 integer, d1 integer, d2 integer, d3 integer, d4 integer, d5 integer, d6 integer, d7 integer, d8 integer, d9 integer, d10 integer, d11 integer, d12 integer, d13 integer, d14 integer, d15 integer, d16 integer, d17 integer);

INSERT INTO nums select generate_series(80000001, 200000000) AS uid, (random() * 23000)::integer + 5600000 AS id_1, (random() * 25000)::integer + 5600000 AS id_2, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d1, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d2, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d3, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d4, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d5, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d6, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d7, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d8, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d9, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d10, (random() * 1000)::integer AS d11, (random() * 100)::integer AS d12, (random() * 100)::integer AS d13, (random() * 100)::integer AS d14, (random() * 100)::integer AS d15, (random() * 100)::integer AS d16, (random() * 100)::integer AS d17;

create index id_1_idx on nums (id_1);
create index id_2_idx on nums (id_2);
cluster nums using id_1_idx;
```

...resulting into the following (both cold reads):

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_1 = 5606001;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using id_1_idx on nums  (cost=0.57..5816.92 rows=5198 width=80) (actual time=1.680..6.394 rows=5185 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id_1 = 5606001)
   Buffers: shared read=88
   I/O Timings: read=4.397
 Planning Time: 4.002 ms
 Execution Time: 7.475 ms
(6 rows)

Time: 15.924 ms
```

...and for `id_2`:

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_2 = 5606001; 
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using id_2_idx on nums  (cost=0.57..5346.53 rows=4777 width=80) (actual time=0.376..985.689 rows=4748 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id_2 = 5606001)
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=4755
   I/O Timings: read=972.555
 Planning Time: 0.203 ms
 Execution Time: 986.590 ms
(6 rows)

Time: 987.296 ms
```

So although my table is "just" 12 GiB + 3x 2.5 GiB (PK + 2 indexes) is is still fast enough.

In case the server already is running on SSD, please make sure to (physically) separate data storage for WAL/log, table data (tablespace), indexes (tablespace) to benefit as much as possible from parallelism and to reduce I/O interference caused by other services/applications on the same system.

Also think about a server system with way more memory for the table and index data (for this ~ 48 GiB table + ~10 GiB per index, assuming all `integer` columns) and then do a warm-up to push data from disk into memory. At least indexes *should* be able to completely stay in memory.

**EDIT**:
The reason my server does not use a bitmap (index + heap) scan is because I am running on SSD and I have adapted the random page cost from default of `4` down to `1.1`. For an HDD system, that would make no sense, of course.

**EDIT #2**:
A retest of the situation has revealed an interesting behavior:

In my test, I assumed the first column `uid` to be the primary key column and be a `serial` (sequential integer), by which the entries are initially sorted on disk. While generating the data, the values for the both interesting indexed columns `id_1` and `id_2` are generated randomly, which usually ends up being worst case for big tables.

However, not so in this case. After creating the test data and the indexes and after analyzing the table **but before** the data reordering using the index on column `id_1` I am getting these results now:

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_1 = 5606001;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on nums  (cost=63.32..7761.68 rows=5194 width=80) (actual time=1.978..41.007 rows=5210 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (id_1 = 5606001)
   Heap Blocks: exact=5198
   Buffers: shared read=5217
   I/O Timings: read=28.732
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on id_1_idx  (cost=0.00..62.02 rows=5194 width=0) (actual time=1.176..1.176 rows=5210 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id_1 = 5606001)
         Buffers: shared read=19
         I/O Timings: read=0.124
 Planning Time: 7.214 ms
 Execution Time: 41.419 ms
(11 rows)
```

...and:

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_2 = 5606001;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on nums  (cost=58.52..7133.04 rows=4768 width=80) (actual time=7.305..43.830 rows=4813 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (id_2 = 5606001)
   Heap Blocks: exact=4805
   Buffers: shared hit=12 read=4810
   I/O Timings: read=28.181
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on id_2_idx  (cost=0.00..57.33 rows=4768 width=0) (actual time=5.102..5.102 rows=4813 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id_2 = 5606001)
         Buffers: shared read=17
         I/O Timings: read=2.414
 Planning Time: 0.227 ms
 Execution Time: 44.197 ms
(11 rows)
```

All plans + optimizations available here:

- [using id_1_idx](https://explain.depesz.com/s/za8e)
- [using id_2_idx](https://explain.depesz.com/s/SquX)

I also followed my own best practices and separated out the indexes to another tablespace on different physical SSD here.

As we can see, to fetch the ~5000 resulting rows it has to read more or less the same number of blocks here, in both cases using the bitmap heap scan.

The correlation for the two columns in this case:

```sql
 attname | correlation | n_distinct 
---------+-------------+------------
 id_1    |  -0.0047043 |      23003
 id_2    |  0.00157998 |      25004
```

Now, retesting the queries **after** the `CLUSTER ... USING id_1_idx` and **after** re-analyzing it, resulting in the following correlation:

```sql
 attname | correlation  | n_distinct 
---------+--------------+------------
 id_1    |            1 |      22801
 id_2    | -0.000898521 |      24997
```

...revealed the following performances:

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_1 = 5606001;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using id_1_idx on nums  (cost=0.57..179.02 rows=5083 width=80) (actual time=2.604..5.256 rows=5210 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id_1 = 5606001)
   Buffers: shared read=90
   I/O Timings: read=4.107
 Planning Time: 4.039 ms
 Execution Time: 5.563 ms
(6 rows)
```

...which is much better - just as expected - but:

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_2 = 5606001;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on nums  (cost=58.57..7140.12 rows=4775 width=80) (actual time=5.866..99.707 rows=4813 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (id_2 = 5606001)
   Heap Blocks: exact=4806
   Buffers: shared read=4823
   I/O Timings: read=31.389
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on id_2_idx  (cost=0.00..57.38 rows=4775 width=0) (actual time=2.992..2.992 rows=4813 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id_2 = 5606001)
         Buffers: shared read=17
         I/O Timings: read=0.338
 Planning Time: 0.210 ms
 Execution Time: 100.155 ms
(11 rows)
```

...more than **twice as slow**, despite the fact that almost the exact same number of blocks had to be read as in the first random run.

Why does it slow down so much?

The physical re-ordering of the table data using index `id_1_idx` also affected the physical order for the column. Now, the purpose of the bitmap heap scan is to get a list of blocks to read in physical (on-disk) order from the bitmap index scan. In the first case (random), there was quite a good chance that multiple rows matching the criteria where located in consecutive blocks on-disk, resulting in less random disk access.

Interestingly (but this might just be because I am running on SSD), disabling the bitmap scan revealed acceptable numbers:

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from nums where id_2 = 5606001;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using id_2_idx on nums  (cost=0.57..7257.12 rows=4775 width=80) (actual time=0.151..35.453 rows=4813 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id_2 = 5606001)
   Buffers: shared read=4823
   I/O Timings: read=30.051
 Planning Time: 1.927 ms
 Execution Time: 35.810 ms
(6 rows)
```

All these numbers are almost complete cold-start executions (as you can see with no or very low `Buffers: shared hit` numbers.

Interesting also is that the I/O timings are pretty similar between the bitmap scan and index scan for `id_2`, but the bitmap scan seems to introduce a huge overhead here.

Comment: I think the optimizer is right. Look at the number of blocks touched by the queries.

Comment: Well, the number of blocks is provided by executing the query. If the planner would have foreseen this huge difference in blocks required to read we would have seen much higher cost for the bitmap heap scan but it's not much different from the index scan. That indicates that there is a discrepancy in complexity which is not accounted for by the planner. Obviously, and totally understandable, the planner does not seem to account for I/O latency in the cost calculation, which may be an additional reason for the costs to be pretty close to each other in both OP-presented queries.

Comment: There is something to what you say, since the `correlation` is not so different in both cases. But the number of blocks visited shouldn't be higher in a bitmap index scan than in a normal index scan, so there really is a difference, albeit a bigger one than the optimizer realizes. I wonder if an `ANALYZE` would improve the cost estimates.

Comment: No, an `ANALYZE` doesn't help here - I've tested that as well. This is due to the fact that - as you also pointed out in your answer - that the index-only scan on index `id_1_idx` already finds all the pages sequentially on disk and hence only has a read X blocks in order to retrieve all the rows for the criteria. For index `id_2_idx` the situation is actually what the bitmap index was built for with the hope that at least some of the ordered blocks will result into sequential continuous disk reads, which doesn't seem to happen here - only one occurrence every X blocks.

Comment: You cannot have an index only scan with `SELECT *`. We seem to agree on all other points. How could you test if an `ANALYZE` on OP's table improves the correlation estimate or not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I've used the word "only" between those other two words "index" and "scan" ... ;-) I said an `ANALYZE` would not help simply because the row estimates are very close to the actual rows in both cases which reflects that the planner already is using up-to-date statistics here. Also, as we already figured out, there is no easy way to correlate rows matching a value for index `id_1_idx` to rows matching a value for index `id_2_idx` and you can have good correlation for one but not the other. We'd need flip-flop ordering per value of `id_1_idx` here... :P

Comment: Oh I see. I tried to explain in my answer that the correlation is not between the two columns, but between the logical and the physical order for each column.

Comment: I know. I just did a retest and detected something pretty interesting. I'll add that finding to my answer.

Comment: "Buffers: shared hit" are the blocks that come from shared buffers, so it is *not* a cold start.

Comment: That's why I wrote the second-last sentence in the update: _almost complete cold-start_. Additionally, do you really want to argue that 12 out of 4822 blocks being cache hits makes a fundamental difference in performance? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread - I assumed you were talking about the last execution plan in your answer with `Buffers: shared read=4823`.

Comment: All indicators are pointing to a HDD drive, but it actually should be SSD drive as we use Azure Database for Postgresql service with [General Purpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-pricing-tiers) tier instance that should have SSD:s as standard disk storage and 5 gb ram per core. We have 4 cores -> 20gb ram.

Comment: @RaimoGIS OMG! I think your (or also my) expectation of an enterprise-level SSD storage for databases is way off with what Azure offers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-pricing-tiers#storage
 I am easily exceeding 7000 IOPS here with my 8 years old consumer SSD

Comment: Yup! The more deeply I look into this, the more surprised I am. It seems that they are actually limiting the IOPS based on how much storage you buy in 3:1 ratio. So you get 300 IOPS with 100gb of storage! We have now 250 GB storage and that equals to 750 IOPS.. :(

Comment: That's why Amazon RDS uses provisioned SSD IOPS to let you decide how much performance you need independently of the storage size: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `id_1` is highly correlated, i.e. the order of that column corresponds to the physical order of the rows, while `id_2` is not correlated.

Test with

```
SELECT attname, correlation
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'mytable'
  AND attname IN ('id_1', 'id_2');
```

If the correlation is high, the rows for a single value of the column will be in a few adjacent blocks of the table. If the correlation is low, the rows will be all over the table and many more blocks have to be read.

To achieve high correlation, you can rewrite a table using the `CLUSTER` statement to reorder the rows. If there are no deletes and updates, a table will be physically ordered in insertion order.

You can speed up one query or the other, but not both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is indeed that the id_1 has better correlation than id_2. Unfortunately I need to make both queries faster. So far it seems to boils down to a hardware problem as pointed out in Ancoron's answer. The correlation results: id_2 :  0.116976 and id_1: -0.204992. I would have assumed a bigger difference actually since I know that all id_1 are fully sequential.

Comment: Hm, yes, that's surprising. Does it change when you `ANALYZE` the table? Fast storage can help, but you would profit most if you can keep as much of the table as possible in RAM.